# Using redux-form's Field with additional props

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-form

I would like to create a higher-order component that renders the `Field` component of the `redux-form` library. My problem is that I would like to like to also pass other props that decorate the component with a `label`, for example. I would also like these input components to be usable *without* Redux form.

One way of accomplishing this would be to do the following:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <label>{props.label}</label>
            <Field name={props.name} component="input" type="text" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is good, but `redux-form` throws an error if this component is rendered without having been wrapped in `reduxForm({})`.

Another way would be to do the following:

```
<Field component={MyComponent} name="my-component" type="text" />
```

But this doesn't allow me to pass extra props, like `label` to `MyComponent`.

The current solution that I have come up with is to pass a `form={false}` prop to `MyComponent` to render an `<input>` if the component is *not* in a form and a `<Field>` if the component *is* in a form. This seems like an inelegant solution, as I'd rather render the same component regardless and not pass an extra `form` prop.

Is there functionality in `redux-form` that allows passing of extra props to `<Field>` or that allows `<Field>` to be rendered outside of the context of a form? Or is this a limitation of `redux-form`?

Comment: Field will pass on other properties to the rendered component, at least it does currently.